# Validate hexadecimal value in Perl using xdigit

Tags: regex, perl, hex

I'm trying to validate a variable in my perl script if it's a hexadecimal or not.

I Googled this and found out about xdigit and other possible methods. I want to use  xdigit only.

But I couldn't find a sample script/snippet on how to use xdigit properly!

**EDIT:**

I don't have any code for this. I need to take a variable, say $sz which may contain a a valid hex value (00004a4c) or invalid hex value (some-alpha-numeric). I need to validate this $sz is holding proper hexadecimal or not.

In a website, I saw this:

**Checking a string whether it is the hexadecimal representation of some number (i.e. consists only of hexadecimal digits) is easily done with a regex. Assuming your string is in $_,**

```
/[[:xdigit:]]+$_/;
```

So I tried the below:

```
$sz =~ /[[:xdigit:]]+$_/;
```

I couldn't understand how I can use this correctly to my purpose.

Comment: It would be easier to help out if you provided some sample input and explained what `$elems[0]` is supposed to be.

Comment: @mob. Thanks. I should've been clear with my query. I'm new to Perl. Updated it now.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If `$_` holds the string you're trying to validate, why are you putting it *in* the regular expression itself? If you lifted that from a web page, you should forget you ever saw that page.

Comment: @Shawn. I don't understand your question. May be due to my inadequate basic knowledge on Perl, thus not aware of $_. I initially tried $sz=~/[[:xdigit:]+\$entry], $entry being the word holder. But I couldn't get it work. I should have studied a bit more and figured this out myself.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string consists entire of hex digits, you could use

```
$sz =~ /^[[:xdigit:]]+\z/     # Consist entirely of hex digits
```

or

```
$sz !~ /[^[:xdigit:]]/        # Doesn't contain non-hex digits
```